# CakePHP 3: Admin Plugin & Routing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

for the purpose of migration to cakephp 3 and mastering the skills of making applications on this version of the framework, I just baked app and plugin.

I want to separate the web application in plugins, Admin, Customers, etc.

I'm fine to access locations within the plugin, for example myapp/admin/users, myapp/admin/,  but if I try to visit the url myapp/admin (without the slash at the end) I have to redirect the location myapp/webroot/admin/.

in myapp/webroot/ I have a theme folder called admin, I tried to change the name in admintheme, but still have a redirect.

How to solve this?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you show your routes.php file?

Comment: Currently there is nothing in route.php, except as default. I tried to add, ( ```$routes->connect ('/admin', ['plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);``` ) but it did not work. My admin plugin also has its route.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This works with cakephp 3.1.2**

Step 1: Set the routes for `admin` prefix above your normal `/`

```
// code ... 

// for prefix admin
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

// for the non-prefix routes
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
// more code ...
```

Step 2: Create a folder called Admin inside your Controllers folder

Dump the appropriate Controller there.

```
 Controller
    |
    |------Admin
    |        |
    |        |----- AppController.php
    |        |---- ProductsController.php // this handles all the admin actions  
    |        
    |----- ProductsController.php // this handles the  non-prefix actions
```

Step 3: Ensure all the Controllers inside the Admin folder use the namespace `namespace App\Controller\Admin;`

Step 4: Make all the Controllers inside the Admin folder extend the AppController **inside** the Admin folder

Step 5: Add this in your beforeFilter for App/Controller/Admin/AppController

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) 
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->theme('AppUI'); // AppUI is my plugin name
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('AppUI.backend'); 
    }
```

Why this works?

Because theme now should be a plugin. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html#themes

And I quote

> Themes in CakePHP are simply **plugins** that focus on providing template
>   files.

Like this:

```
 plugins
    |
    |------AppUI
    |        |
    |        |----- src
             |        |
             |        |---- Template
                      |        |---- Layout
                               |        |---- backend.ctp
```